# SQL group by и order by вместе

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

составляю sql запрос через query builer в code igniter. Возникла такая проблема:

Нужно получить список диалогов пользователя, имеются следующие таблицы:

```
users:
id | nick | avatar

messages:
id | user_id | text | date
```

Пробовал два варианта:

```
$this->db->select('m.*, u.avatar, u.nick')
    ->from('users u')
    ->join($this->table . ' m', 'u.id = m.user_id', 'left')
    ->having("m.id != ''")
    ->group_by('m.user_id')
    ->order_by('m.date', 'desc');
```

и

```
$this->db->select('m.*, u.avatar, max(m.date)')
    ->from($this->table . ' m')
    ->join('users u', 'u.id = m.user_id', 'left')
    ->group_by('m.user_id')
    ->order_by('m.date', 'desc');
```

Сама проблема заключается в том, что список диалогов получается, но в качестве последнего сообщения - выводит первое сообщение и order by словно совсем не работает, пробовал и max(), и несколько колонок в group by. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Для списка диалогов пользователя, `GROUP BY` не нужен вообще

```
$this->db->select('m.*, u.avatar')
    ->from($this->table . ' m')
    ->join('users u', 'u.id = m.user_id', 'left')
    ->order_by('m.date', 'desc');
```

Comment: Так у меня сейчас выводятся все сообщения абсолютно, мне нужно их сгруппировать в диалоги

Comment: @Alexey Что такое у вас `диалог`? В вашей базе такого понятия нет

Comment: У меня много сообщений между пользователями и я хочу их сгруппировать так, чтобы выглядело, как список диалогов

Comment: @Alexey У вас сообщения не **между** пользователями, а **от** пользователя. Кому предназначалось сообщения у вас неизвестно, а значит и диалог построить не удастся. Вам, как минимум, нужно завести еще одну таблицу `dialogs` и в каждом сообщении указывать `id` диалога, в котором оно писалось

Comment: Сообщения между пользователями и админом. Забыл упомянуть

Comment: Точнее от пользователей для админа

Comment: @Alexey Вы так и не ответили, что такое у вас `диалог`